# Could you tell be debug process in Phonegap iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cordova

I am developing iOS phone gap application. I want to know any good debug process for iOS phone gap application.

Answer (score 2):

With the release of iOS 6, Apple released remote Web Inspector for their Mobile Safari in conjunction with Mac Safari 6, and this is huge. Basically you have all the features and power of Web Inspector in regular Safari, for your mobile apps, including Phonegap apps.
Here's how it works,
Requires xCode 4.5+ running an iOS 6+ simulator (or an iOS 6+ device), and Safari 6+.

Steps:

1. In your ios6 simulator or ios6 device,open settings --> Safari -->
   Advanced --> Web Inspector --> (turn On) .
2. Run your phoneGap/Cordova app.
3. In Safari 6+ (From Mac),  access ios Simulator or ios device from the Develop menu. You can enable Develop menu in Safari's Advanced
   Preferences.
4. Now You can debug the app using Web Inspector.

For More, look for "REMOTE DEBUGGING" in http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone-5-ios-6-html5-developers.

Answer (score 1):

`http://www.iwebinspector.com/` will help you debugging Javascript. say Phonegap client code.

Also phone gap has [service](http://debug.phonegap.com/) for client debugging which is based on [weinre](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre)

For server side if you are using Xcode, You can check in console itself.