# How to measure execution time of JavaScript function in Safari with microsecond precision?

Tags: javascript, cordova, safari

As in title. I know about "High Resolution Time" http://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time/, but it doesn't work in Safari. Are there any other options?

**EDIT:**
I need to measure time of single SELECT in WebSQL. Now it's time is about 1-2 millisecond. I need more precision then that.

**EDIT 2:**
I developing iOS app with PhoneGap, so I can't change browser. It have to be Safari.

Comment: So if the primary reason is to micro-measure performance of SQL, why not do the performance measuring in a browser that DOES support the high resolution timing API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Console API's time() and timeEnd() methods I seem to get better precision:

```
> console.time('a')
> console.timeEnd('a')
[Debug] a: 5895.467ms
```

See the Safari documentation for details: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Console/Console.html

Comment: Almost, but I need the value of this time interval. And var interval = console.timeEnd('a'); doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe parse the console output using a Cordova plugin (and if required, send it back to the webview)? :p 

You could use org.apache.cordova.console as a template: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console/blob/master/src/ios/CDVLogger.m

Comment: On PhoneGap I use your answer with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044779/phonegap-ios-safari-debug-workflow to access console while running app on iPhone. But I need to test it also on Sencha Touch - I start with new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044779/phonegap-ios-safari-debug-workflow

Comment: I made mistake with the second link. I start with new question at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075392/get-access-to-console-in-sencha-touch-app-running-on-iphone