# Get access to console in Sencha Touch app running on iPhone

Tags: ios, sencha-touch, mobile-safari

I want to use console.time('a') and console.timeEnd('a') in my Sencha Touch iOS app. This functions prinnt measured time in microseconds on console.

**How to get access to console while I'm running my app on iPhone?**

I tried with Safari Remote Web Inspector (like [Phonegap iOS Safari debug workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044779/phonegap-ios-safari-debug-workflow)), but it doesn't work. It give me access to index.html, and Web Inspector opens correctly, but all his tabs are empty including console tab.

(I tried used Safari Remote Web Inspector with PhoneGap and it works correctly)

**EDIT:**
I don't use Xcode, becouse I am building my app with Sencha Cmd. And I do not want to change that, because I am testing Sencha Touch performance without PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [cordova plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console/blob/master/doc/index.md) which you can use to see the output of console in XCode.

Comment: I don't use Xcode, becouse I am building my app with Sencha Cmd. And I do not want to change that, because I am testing Sencha Touch performance without PhoneGap.